# Reprojecting Tiles Using PixelBender in a Flex Client

Tags: flex

I am pondering the possibility of somehow reprojecting tiles for display in my Flex application using Pixel Bender or something equivalent.  The tile cache in question here is not owned/maintained by me, so I have no control over its output.  I know I could use ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer to reproject to the desired coordinate system, but that will be very slow.

Hopefully the following use case explains the need to do so:  I have a Flex app that is using ESRI ArcGIS Online basemaps in the standard Web Mercator projection.  I use a service that returns polygons around and over the polar regions.  Displaying in the Web Mercator projection looks like crap.

So, I guess my questions are:
1.  Does anyone know of any good examples/tutorials...etc showing how this can be done?
2.  Will this overwhelm the processing power of the client browser?

Answer (score 1):

While possible, I think you would be better off using a basemap that supports the polar regions.  Either an "un-projected geographic" that at least cover the poles (as supposed to web mercator). Or one projection focused on the north pole and another on the south pole.

Some example "un-projected" services are:
http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer
http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer 
http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_ShadedRelief_World_2D/MapServer
http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/I3_Imagery_Prime_World_2D/MapServer